# Relation between Leslie dinamical system matrix and homogeneous 3rd degree recurrence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrence-relations, matrix-equations, mathematical-modeling

For a simple Leslie Matrix and asociated system we can get the value of a vector $x_0$ by using $X_{n+1}=AX_N$. For example with the following system $X_{N+1}=AX_N=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3 & 5\\
0.2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.4 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
c_n\\
j_n\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{cases}
             c_{n+1}=3j_n+5a_n\\
              j_{n+1}=0.2c_n\\
               a_{n+1}=0.4j_n
             \end{cases}$

But I noticed that by making some substitutions I get to a third order recurrence relations for $c_n$: $c_{n+3}=0.6c_{n+1}+0.4c_n$ and its characteristic equation is the same as the matrix one. (with roots  $\lambda_1=1 $, $\lambda_2=-0.5+0.38i$, $\lambda_3=-0.5-0.38i$)

But how I can use only this recurrence to get a $\begin{pmatrix}
c_n\\
j_n\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}$ vector from some $x_0$? as I do with the matrix, I think I´m strugling with complex numbers in development of solutions.
For example with $x_0=\begin{pmatrix}
10\\
8\\
12
\end{pmatrix}$ by making $A^3X_0$ I get $x_3=$$\begin{pmatrix}
54.4\\
4.4\\
6.72
\end{pmatrix}$

How can I do the same without using the matrix, only with the $c_n$ recurrence relation?

Comment: To the OP. On this website, usage is, if one is satisfied with an answer, then one upvotes it and (or) one gives the green ticket or, if one is not satisfied, then one writes why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$spectrum(A)=\{1,a,\overline{a}\}$ where $a=-1/2+i\sqrt{15}/10$. satisfies $|a|<1$. In this case, $A^n$ depends on the Im,Re parts of $a^n$. Then we have no closed forms for $A^n$ (in the sense that $(a+ib)^n+(a-ib)^n$ has no REAL closed form); if we want the EXACT value of $A^n$, then we must use some recurrence calculation.

Let $c=Re(a^n),f=Im(a^n)$. We obtain

[image]

where $c,f$ are given by the recurrence

[image]

Yet, if we want only an APPROXIMATION of $A^n$, then it suffices to ask for an approximation of $c,f$, that is much faster. It is easy to check the validity of the result, using the fact that $5^nA^n$ is an integer matrix.